# Cannot convert the "System.Char[,]" value of type "System.Char[,]" to type "System.Char"

Tags: function, powershell, arguments

I've got simple script, which creates 2d char array, and invokes function, which should to fill that array with given char.

```
[int]$size = Read-Host "Please, enter the board size"

$playerBoard = New-Object 'char[,]' $size,$size

Fill-Boad-With-Symbol($playerBoard,'*',$size)
```

and here is the function

```
function   Fill-Boad-With-Symbol([char[,]]$board, [char]$symbol,[int]$boardSize){
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $boardSize; $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j -lt $boardSize; $j++) {
            $board[$i,$j] = $symbol
        }
    }
}
```

But when executing this code i get the following error:

```
  Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'board'. Cannot convert the "System.Char[,]" value of type "System.Char[,]" to type "System.Char"
...
+ Fill-Boad-With-Symbol($playerBoard,'*',$size)
```

I kindly ask to explain, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your expected output once the `$playerBoard` has been passed through `Fill-Boad-With-Symbol`?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I expect that $playerBoard will be filled with '*'

Comment: Your error is because of the way you're calling your function, in PS the arguments are named or positional and each argument is separated by a space => `Fill-Boad-With-Symbol $playerBoard '*' $size`. I also think you have a wrong expectation of how `New-Object 'char[,]' $size,$size` will look in the console.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, i expect, that ``` New-Object 'char[,]' $size,$size``` will look as 2d array

Comment: It will be a 2d array but it will not look like you expect it to look. it will be a vertical line on the console.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, i know, i have separate function to print it as 2d array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment, in PowerShell, arguments are either positional or named, your first error is the way you're passing arguments to your function. By doing this:

```
Fill-Board-Symbol($playerBoard,'*',$size)
```

PowerShell will interpret it as if you were passing an `object[]` (object `array`) which 1st element `array[0]` will be the `$playerBoard`, 2nd element would be a `*` and 3rd element, an `int` to the first parameter of your function **`-Board`**  which is type constraint to `char[,]`.

PowerShell will then attempt type conversion from `object[]` to `char[,]` and it will fail with that exception you see.

Example:

Given these variables:

```
$playerBoard = New-Object 'char[,]' 2,2
$symbol = '*'
$size = 2
```

Grouping them together `(...)` we can inspect it's type:

```
PS /> ($playerBoard, $symbol, $size).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name         BaseType
-------- -------- ----         --------
True     True     Object[]     System.Array
```

If we attempt to convert it to `[char[,]]`:

```
PS /> [char[,]]($playerBoard, $symbol, $size)
```

> InvalidArgument: Cannot convert the "System.Char[,]" value of type "System.Char[,]" to type "System.Char".

Try doing this instead:

```
[int]$size = Read-Host "Please, enter the board size"
$playerBoard = New-Object 'char[,]' $size,$size

function Fill-Board-With-Symbol {
param(
    [char[,]]$board,
    [char]$symbol,
    [int]$boardSize
)
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $boardSize; $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j -lt $boardSize; $j++) {
            $board[$i,$j] = $symbol
        }
    }
    $board # => This is your output
}

$newBoard = Fill-Board-With-Symbol -Board $playerBoard -Symbol '*' -BoardSize $size
$newBoard
```